# Can XSLT remove DOCTYPE declaration from XML source file before transforming?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can XSLT remove `<!DOCTYPE ... "some.dtd">` from an XML file before transforming it? The DTD is not present in the directory in which the XML file resides so I get an I/O error when attempting to transform.

I'm planning on transforming multiple XML files so manually removing or commenting out the DOCTYPE declaration is not an option.

Comment: What API are you calling in order to use XSLT?

Comment: These days there are XML parsers allowing you to ignore a DTD. So which XSLT processor with which XML parser on which platform do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT, as an API, just reads XML files. By the time the content is available to XSLT, the DOCTYPE has been processed -- or given you an error. You need to configure the process of reading the XML file to ignore the DTD or to find the DTD in a known location.